# use jquery to add external webpage to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, append

I have the following piece of code to load a GIF while ajax takes a `div` and appends some content:

```
var loader = '<img id="loader" src="loading.gif"/>';

$(loader).appendTo('#container').load(function() {
    $('#container').find('#loader').delay(3000).fadeOut(function() {
        $('#container').append('content')
    })
});
```

How can I modify this code so instead of appending `'content'`, it would append a `div` from an external webpage.

For example the GIF will fadeout, and inside of the container `div` will be `www.somesite.com #somediv`.

Thanks,
Katie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-domain XHR is possible by using the [YUL library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) by Yahoo!. It basically uses the server to fetch the content for you to bypass the [policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as [Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471800/hamish) mentioned.

For more information, please see: [The jQuery Cross-Domain Ajax Guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide)

Comment: i think what I am trying to do is much simpler than what I have asked
all i want to do is have a loading gif that runs for x amount of time even if the ajax request is finished - I am trying to have a tv display static while content is fetched
here is the site I am working on www.uvm.edu/~areid/test/demo.html

Comment: @katiebekell - The point is you cannot `append a div from an external webpage`. This is forbidden by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: can i use something other than append? I was under the impression that ajax was for fetching content without reloading the page. perhaps i am just confusing append with another function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.

You could, however, use an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe) to embed part a whole page in your page.

Comment: what is the load function for in that piece of code - i thought that was ajax which is used to do exactly that

Comment: @Hamish - You should also add a side note that `iframe` will not work in webpages with `x-frame deny` headers. For example, [Google](http://www.google.com/)